# How to eliminate the image saw-toothed appearance after capturing it and setting it to a PDF file?

Tags: android, image, pdf

I have an app with 2 activities: MainActivity and PhotoActivity. It generates a PDF format report file using iText library. From Main, it's possible to call the PhotoActivity, and here there's a button to call the Android camera, using android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE. I decalred a public bitmap array on Main to keep multiple images in case the user needs to take more than 1 picture and it is working fine.

The only problem now is that the images are experiencing a kind of line aliasing (saw-toothed appearance) once set to PDF file. It looks like the app is taking the exact imageView image and setting to the PDF file. So it goes a tiny image to a 210 x 297mm page, and when I try to programmatically upscale it, it gets saw-toothed, low resolution like. Instead, I want to take the high resolution picture that the user just took and shrink a little bit just to fit one or two in the same page, but keeping an acceptable quality.

My camera has 5M Pixels, and it is set to maximum resolution. Could anyone please point out what I doing wrong here?

The image adding code of MainActivity is below:

```
public static ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    private void addImage(Document document) {

    Image myImg = null;
    document.newPage();

    for(Bitmap bitmap : bitmaps){

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    //    stream.flush();
    //    stream.close();
        myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
        myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);
        myImg.scaleAbsolute(400, 600);
        document.add(myImg);

        } catch (BadElementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And the code of the PhotoActivity is below:

```
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

   // iv.setImageBitmap(MainActivity.bitmaps);

    if(MainActivity.bitmaps.size() > 0){

        iv.setImageBitmap(MainActivity.bitmaps.get(MainActivity.bitmaps.size()-1));
    }
}

        @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            MainActivity.bitmaps.add((Bitmap) extras.get("data"));
            iv.setImageBitmap(MainActivity.bitmaps.get(MainActivity.bitmaps.size()-1));
        }

        else if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            MainActivity.bitmaps.add(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            iv.setImageBitmap(MainActivity.bitmaps.get(MainActivity.bitmaps.size()-1));
        }
    }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: yes this issue will occur if you capture image via ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent, because in onActivityResult() you will get the thumbnail image (bitmap) as resultant Image.

Comment: Any sugestions for an alternative method of image capture?